# Is there a way to display a plot or image for a set period of time (seconds)?

Tags: shiny

The problem i am having is that i have to create an psychological online experiment. I won't get into all the details, however, one aspect involves displaying an image or plot for a set number of seconds. I have started learning Shiny and I am two hours into it, (as i am relatively good with R, and it seemed a good step) however i cannot find a way to do this.

I know showNotification has a "duration" attribute, but I found nothing for showPlot, or Image.

Is there a way to do this, or should I quit Shiny while I haven't lost much time?

Greetings,
George

**EDIT: wow. more or less is what I want. Thank you all!**

Since details were asked (and thank you for that), the experiment requires only one image. there will be two experimental conditions, and both will have one plot to show (that plot i intend to draw with ggplot2) and contains a number of 30-50 points for about 4 seconds. The subject will have to evaluate the number of points (since he can't count them) and insert it in a field, and the subject will have to then evaluate certain evaluation parameters. data that will be reused to compare him to others. that is about it!

Since it is now obviously possible to do this, i will begin with a serious approach to Shiny. Thank you all!

Comment: You mean displaying an image one after the other ? How many images are there ? Is it a fixed number ?

Comment: Please see `?invalidateLater`

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do this in shiny.
You can use a `reactiveTimer` for example

```
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {

    # every 2 seconds.
    autoHide <- reactiveTimer(2000)

    display <- TRUE

    observe({
      # re-execute this reactive expression every time the
      # timer fires.
      autoHide()
      display <- if_else(display,FALSE,TRUE)
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      autoHide()
      if(display){
      hist(rnorm(200))
      } else {
        hist(rnorm(100))
      }
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `slick.js` JavaScript library. You have to download the zip file [here](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and extract it in the `www` subfolder of your app.

```
library(shiny)

# images to be displayed ####
## these images are in the www subfolder
images <- c("img1.JPG", "img2.JPG", "img3.JPG", "img4.JPG", "img5.JPG")

# ui #####
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css",
              href="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"),
    tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css",
              href="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css"),
    tags$script(type="text/javascript", 
                src="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(
"$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#images').slick({
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 500,
    infinite: false
  }).on('afterChange', function(e, slick, cur){
      if(cur === slick.$slides.length-1){
        slick.setOption('autoplay', false, true);
    }
  });
});")),
    tags$style(HTML(
"#images .slick-prev {
    position:absolute;
  top:65px; 
  left:-50px;
}
#images .slick-next {
  position:absolute;
  top:95px; 
  left:-50px;
}
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { 
    color:red !important;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.content {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 90%;
}"))
  ),
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      # empty sidebar #
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tags$div(class="content",
               do.call(function(...) tags$div(id="images", ...), 
                       lapply(seq_along(images), function(i){
                         uiOutput(paste0("img",i))
                       })
               )
      )
    )
  )
)

# server #####
server <- function(input, output) {

  lapply(seq_along(images), function(i){
    output[[paste0("img",i)]] <- renderUI({
      tags$img(src = images[i], width = "400px", height = "400px")
    })
  })

}

# Run the application #### 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Is it something like this you want ? We could try to add a "Go" button because here the autoplaying slideshow runs at the startup. Though this is not necessary: to stop the slideshow, it suffices to put the mouse cursor on the image.

---

## EDIT

Here is the version with a "Go" button.

```
library(shiny)

# images to be displayed ####
## these images are in the www subfolder
images <- c("img1.JPG", "img2.JPG", "img3.JPG", "img4.JPG", "img5.JPG")

# ui #####
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css",
              href="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"),
    tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css",
              href="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css"),
    tags$script(type="text/javascript", 
                src="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(
      "function runSlick(x){
  $('#images').slick({
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 500,
    infinite: false
  }).on('afterChange', function(e, slick, cur){
      if(cur === slick.$slides.length-1){
        slick.setOption('autoplay', false, true);
    }
  });
};
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('runSlick', runSlick);")),
    tags$style(HTML(
      "#images .slick-prev {
    position:absolute;
  top:65px; 
  left:-50px;
}
#images .slick-next {
  position:absolute;
  top:95px; 
  left:-50px;
}
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { 
    color:red !important;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.content {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 90%;
}"))
  ),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("go", "Go!")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        "input.go > 0",
        tags$div(class="content",
                 do.call(function(...) tags$div(id="images", ...), 
                         lapply(seq_along(images), function(i){
                           uiOutput(paste0("img",i))
                         })
                 )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# server #####
server <- function(input, output, session){

  lapply(seq_along(images), function(i){
    output[[paste0("img",i)]] <- renderUI({
      tags$img(src = images[i], width = "400px", height = "400px")
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input[["go"]], {
    session$sendCustomMessage("runSlick", "")
  }, once = TRUE)

}

# Run the application #### 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! the experiment requires only one image. there will be two experimental conditions, and both will have one plot to show (that plot i intend to draw with ggplot2) and contains a number of 30-50 points for about 4 seconds. The subject will have to evaluate the number of points (since he can't count them) and insert it in a field, and the subject will have to then evaluate certain evaluation parameters. data that will be reused to compare him to others. that is about it!